# Recursively pointing out the number of files in directories

Tags: bash, shell, find

What would be the command in finding out all directories beneath of a root containing more than a given number of files xyz (assuming xyz is 1000) and saving the output of the returned number(s) and directory/ies in a file (or better: variable)?

Comment: The command is `find`. Then you should check which parameters you can use to get that output. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type d | while read dir; do
    printf '%d\t%s\n' $(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l) "$dir"
done | sort -rn
```

This prints each directory and how many files are in it. It sorts them so the ones with the most files are first.

If you want to limit the printout to directories with at least `$limit` files, then do:

```
find . -type d | while read dir; do
    count=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
    (($count >= $limit)) && printf '%d\t%s\n' "$count" "$dir"
done | sort -rn
```

To make this extra robust and handle unusual file names with whitespace and other special characters in them, add a few flags to `find` and `read`. Technically, file names are allowed to have tabs and newlines in them, so it's a good idea to write scripts defensively so these types of file names don't cause problems.

```
find . -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' -r dir; do
    count=$(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo \; | wc -l)
    (($count >= $limit)) && printf '%d\t%s\n' "$count" "$dir"
done | sort -rn
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `find` and `dirname`:

```
$DIR=/root/dir/to/search     
find "$DIR" -type f -exec dirname {} \; | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '$1>=1000{print}'
```

Recursively finds all files below the current directory, then truncates the filename to leave only the parent directory of each file. These are already sorted, so `uniq -c` will then count the number of files that each directory contains, and awk prints only the ones with more than 1000 files in.

To save the result in a file:

```
find "$DIR" ... | awk '$1>=1000{print}' > file.txt
```

To save in a variable:

```
var=$(find "$DIR" ... | awk '$1>=1000{print}')
```

Comment: Things have changed unfortunately according to my my boss. A specific text file in each folder contains the entire size of all files therein (number #2 out of #3). A given number (100000 KB) is not allowed to cross. How would such recursive query look like providing the file size in case it is > 100000 including the folder name dumped into a variable instead?